# Can I have asp.net core mvc and web api as single project

Tags: asp.net-core

We want to build an asp.net core web application. it contains MVC part for returning Views and API to return JSON and have Restful services for our web application.

So can I have MVC and Web API inside the same project? as currently when i want to create a new project inside .NET 6.0 i have to select the either MVC or Web API type :-

[image]

Comment: Yes. Probably best to start with the Model-View-Controller template, then add your Web API controllers as needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So can I have MVC and Web API inside the same project? as currently when i want to create a new project inside .NET 6.0 i have to select the either MVC or Web API type :-

Certainly you can. What all you need is, you should have one `solution`. Furthermore, within the solution, you ought to create two project. One for `MVC application` and another for `Web API` application. Here is the simulation how you can achieve that:

[image]

**Project Architecture Would be Like:**

[image]

**If you want to run two project together:**

1. Go to your `solution` and `right click on it`
2. `Select Property`
3. Choose `Multiple Startup` Project

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks so you are saying it is better to create 2 separate projects, rather than adding Web API controllers to an MVC project?

Comment: Of course, its good practice to seperate the `Web API` and `MVC Client` app within the same solution. It will certainly make your project loosely coupled. In addition, if you need only few `Web API` controllers then you can consider adding within same project, However, its not mostly followed practice.

Comment: You are welcome and glad to assit you. Let me know if I can assist you further.

Comment: Apart from this, I would suggest you, to make your `MVC Project` completely seperate in two different solution additionally, follow our [`clean architecture pattern`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/modern-web-apps-azure/common-web-application-architectures#clean-architecture) for your `Web API Project`

Comment: I've been looking for an answer to this for a while so thanks a lot, very helpful. However, if I choose to create two solutions to keep them separate (which I might need to do), then, for hosting, would I need to buy two "packages" from a .NET hosting service, one for the web app and one for the API? It seems like I would.